# How to convert a paginated collection in Laravel so that the response is an array of objects

Tags: laravel, api, collections, pagination

I have a list that retrieves all branches, calculates distance between client and branches, sort them and display a paginated result. Everything works fine except that when i paginate i get a response such as: [image]
This is fine except that the outermost wrapping should be an array. Basically i want an array of objects.
This is my controller:

```
class HomescreenController extends Controller
{

    //Get a list of all the branches
    public function branchesNearby($lat, $lng) //Request $request
    {
        $branches = Branch::all();

        //Calculate distance between each branch and client
        //Radius of earth is 6371 KM so multiply the result with radius of earth 6371*pi/180
        foreach ($branches as $branch){
        $branch['distance'] = sqrt(pow(($branch->lat - $lat), 2) + pow(($branch->lng - $lng), 2)) * 108;
        }

        //Sort by nearest first
        $sortedBranches = $branches->sortBy('distance'); //->forPage(1, 2);

        $paginated = $sortedBranches->paginate(2);

        return BranchResource::collection($paginated);
    }
```

To fix it i tried to

```
return BranchResource::collection($paginated)->values()->all();
```

This results in correct formatting like this:
[image]
But it removes my pagination. Somebody please help.

Also, this is my resource:

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'shop' => $this->shop->name,
            'shop_ar' => $this->shop->name_ar,
            'category' => $this->shop->category->name,
            'category_ar' => $this->shop->category->name_ar,
            'shop_image' => asset('api/images/' . $this->shop->image_file),
            //'lat' => $this->lat,
            //'lng' => $this->lng,
            'shop_logo' => asset('api/images/' . $this->shop->logo_file),
            'distance' => $this->distance . " KM"
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom pagination by sending limit and page number
or
change code to

```
$paginated->toArray()
```

Comment: No, that does not work and gives me a `Call to a member function first() on array in file` error